# I cannot locate the SQL Server stored procedure I just created

Tags: sql-server

I am new and I just created a simple SQL Server stored procedure in my database `ABAFunding` called `getUse`, which  executed correctly.

I do not know where it ended up. I read elsewhere I created the problem by forgetting to add the schema `dbo.` to the name before executing. Now I cannot locate the stored procedure.

I created two other procedures months ago with the `dbo.` prefix and they are both listed under `Programmability / Stored Procedures`. I tried recreating the stored procedure as `dbo.getUse` but get an error there is already an object named `getUse` in the database.

I'd like to locate it, delete it, and do it correctly.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: to remove you can use drop proc command

Comment: Did you **refresh** the Object Explorer?

Comment: 1.) refresh.
2.) check in the "master" db.  You may have forgotten to change your database in the dropdown.

Comment: If you are in SSMS you might just need to refresh, have you tried just typing the `Exec dbo.GetUse` try using the `Ctrl + Shift + R` command to get the intellisense to pickup new tables/sp etc.

Comment: Are you sure you created the stored procedure in correct database ???

Comment: This sounds silly, but are you sure you created a stored procedure?  If you paste the `CREATE` statement, we might be able to give more specific answers.  Also, add a `USE [database_name]` before the `CREATE` so you explicitly know what database it's being created in.

Comment: Here is what I did by right-clicking on 'Stored Procedures' under ABAFunding (my DB). I think my issue is I forgot to declare the schema and now I can't find the SP.
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE getUse

--@use VARCHAR(20)

AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;




SELECT *
FROM FundingAnalysis
WHERE FAFundsUsage = @use
END
GO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these 2 steps:

1.) refresh.

2.) check in the "master" db. You may have forgotten to change your database in the dropdown.

**Clarification:** The "master" db is found under "System Databases" > "master"

Comment: After everything I went through to locate it, I had to exit SSMS and log back in to get the procedure to show up.  I thought that by slecting another databse I had refreshed.  Live and learn.  I appreciate all the help

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures are listed under:

```
Your_Database
    - Programmability
        + Stored Procedures
```

Comment: That is where I expected it to be but it is not there.  I have refreshed the Object Explorer

Comment: Then, there's something screwy going on with your instance, or you created in another database than what you thought you were working with. I'd check any other databases on the instance first, and then you might try restarting the server or something if this not a production instance.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you have created it in the correct database execute the following statement and see if it returns your procedure name in results

```
USE your_Database_Name
GO

SELECT Name 
FROM sys.procedures 
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%Your_Proc_Name%'
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I ran the query and get nothing back, but when trying to re-create the sp in ABAFunding I get the following: Msg 2714, Level 16 State 3 Procedure getUse Line 16 There is already an object named getUse in the database  Is it possible to post screen shots or send it somehow?  I ran this quesry against all the possible databases we have and nothing shows up.

Comment: Did you replace `your procedure's name` with `Your_Proc_Name`. I believe your procedure that you are trying to create us called `getUse`. add this bit and try executing the query. and replace `your_Database_Name` with your actual database name.

Comment: I did this and nothing.  Tried it against both DB's.  It is almost like it is an object in the DB but not a procedure, some other type of object.   Is there a higher level table that might look at other options in the DB to locate WHAT is called getUse?